# How to get json response output using Play Framework(Scala) for json objects from Postgresql table?

Tags: json, postgresql, scala, playframework

I am trying to return json response data from Postgresql database using Play framework(Scala). I have tried the following: but I am not able to return my json response output.(As I have couple of json objects in my database table: `jsondata`, which is having id and name). I am getting: "`type mismatch; found : anorm.SqlQuery required: String`". I am not sure where I am doing wrong in my code to get json response output for my json objects from database(controller and model). Please help me regarding this to get the output and Thanks in advance.

controler:

```
import play.api.Play.current
import play.mvc.Controller;           
import play.libs.Json;
import play.libs.Json.*;                        
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;           
import models.Getjsondata
import com.google.gson.Gson
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

 Getjsondata.getJsonValues(Getjsondata(Json.parse(id)), Json.parse(name));
 class MyController extends Controller {
 def getJson = Action { request =>
    println("calling getJson ... !!")//getting this message on play console
    val body: Anyname = request.body
    val textBody: Option[String] = body.asText
    val optionJson = textBody.flatMap(json => Try(Json.parse(json)).toOption)
    val bodyId = optionJson.map(_ \ "id")
    val bodyname = optionJson.map(_ \ "name")
    {
      for {
        id <- bodyId
        name <- bodyname
        json <- optionJson
      } yield {
        println("calling getJson else ... !!")
        val response = Getjsondata.getJsonValues(Getjsondata(id.as[Long],name.as[String]));
        Ok("Json data retrieved successfully: "+response)
      }
    } getOrElse BadRequest("Missing parameter either [id] or [name]")
  }
  }
```

model:

```
import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.json.{Json,JsValue}
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.libs.json._
import anorm.~
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Getjsondata (
  id: Pk[Long], name: String
)
object Getjsondata {
  val extractor = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("jsondata.id") ~
    get[String]("jsondata.name") map {
      case id~name => Getjsondata(id, name)
 }
 }
  def getJsonValues(jsondata: Getjsondata): String = {
  println("addJson getJsonValues page... !")
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
 // SQL("select row_to_json(jsondata) from jsondata");
    SQL("select * from jsondata");//type mismatch; found : anorm.SqlQuery required: String
     }
     println("Test String... !") 
  }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing Scala and Java code. Maybe try with all Scala.

Comment: @Reactormonk, thanks for your reply, Could I know how can I use/write my controller class in Scala ?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the doc and try?

Comment: @cchantep, I have modified the question description, getting the error: type mismatch; found : anorm.SqlQuery required: String, kindly let me know that how to get my json response.

Comment: @Reactormonk, I have modified the question description, kindly let me know where I am doing wrong in my code please.

Answer (score 0):

your `Scala controller` might look like this:

```
class MyController extends Controller {

  def getJson = Action { request =>
    println("calling getJson ... !!")

    val body: AnyContent = request.body
    val textBody: Option[String] = body.asText
    val optionJson = textBody.flatMap(json => Try(Json.parse(json)).toOption)

    val bodyId = optionJson.map(_ \ "id")
    val bodyName = optionJson.map(_ \ "name")

    {
      for {
        id <- bodyId
        name <- bodyName
        json <- optionJson
      } yield {
        println("calling getJson else ... !!")
        Getjsondata.getJsonValues(json)

        Ok("Json data retrieved successfully")
      }
    } getOrElse BadRequest("Missing parameter either [id] or [name]")
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, if I apply the above code, I am getting the error: type mismatch; found : play.api.libs.json.JsValue required: models.Getjsondata (at line: Getjsondata.getJsonValues(json)).

Comment: Yes, your method `Getjsondata.getJsonValues(json)` takes an input value of a type `Getjsondata`. your code in that line should look something like this `Getjsondata.getJsonValues(Getjsondata(myId, myName))` although I am not sure what `Pk[Long]` is. what is PK? (once you tell me that I can show you what need to be changed for this code to run and make sense).

Comment: I have couple of json objects in my Postgreql database, what  I need is: I need to get those json objects (response output) from Postgresql database table(jsondata, which is having id, a Primary key(PK) of Long type and name of String type) using Scala. so that I can display on my view page in any table format.

Comment: Kindly let me know that how can I execute that code to get my json response(both id and name) from database table ? what are changes that  need to happen to work as per requirement ?(in controller and in model class). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have done like: Getjsondata.getJsonValues(Getjsondata(id.as[Long],content.as[String]));, that error is gone, and getting println message: calling getJson ... !!, but I am not getting the json response, getting error: Missing parameter either [id] or [name], don't know why it's not executing ?

Comment: For now in your 'def getJsonValues' change the type to `String` like so `def getJsonValues(jsondata: Getjsondata): String' and add the line `"Test String"` at the bottom of the method's body.

Comment: Now change the `Getjsondata.getJsonValues(Getjsondata(id, name))` to `val response = Getjsondata.getJsonValues(Getjsondata(id, name))` and 'Ok("Json data retrieved successfully)' to `Ok("Json data retrieved successfully: " + response)` just to see that things work smoothing in terms of the program.

Comment: I would suggest that the next step would be to hardcode a working SQL query in ' SQL("select row_to_json(jsondata) from jsondata")'. Something you know works for sure, either `Select * FROM jsondata` or any other query that you tested against your SQL database server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried as per your instructions, but getting the error: type mismatch; found : anorm.SqlQuery required: String, I have modified the question description too, kindly let me know about it please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have done like: def getJsonValues(jsondata: Getjsondata): List[Getjsondata] = { ...SQL("select * from jsondata").as(extractor.*) --- }, the error is gone, I am getting now: Missing parameter either [id] or [name].

Comment: that means that somewhere in this block there is a failure `for {
        id <- bodyId
        name <- bodyname
        json <- optionJson
      } yield {
        println("calling getJson else ... !!")
        val response = Getjsondata.getJsonValues(Getjsondata(id.as[Long],name.as[String]));
        Ok("Json data retrieved successfully: "+response)
      }` either one of your  `bodyId` `bodyname` `optionJson` is a `None`

Comment: yes, I have tried with println messages for bodyId, bodyContent and optionJson: it's displaying "None" for all, I am not sure why it's displaying None, but I have json objects in database.

Comment: Can we have chat discussion for it please ?

Comment: body: AnyContentAsEmpty and textBody: None is showing

Comment: Can we have chat discussion please ?

Comment: can we have chat at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104262/discussion-between-dhana-and-rumoku

Comment: I have created the similar one, but this time I can able to execute my application but I am getting my json response at exception level, I have explained at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619921/runtimeexception-class-org-postgresql-util-pgobject-to-string-for-column-column, can I know anything it ?